# AJAX call returning 404 error due to incorrect content type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

AJAX call returns:

> HTTP Status 404 -
>   /mycustomproject/en/WEB-INF/views/desktop/register/region.jsp

Incidentally, this is the same URL that I am using to make the Ajax call.

```
$( "#address\\.country_del" ).change(function() {
      alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
      $.ajax({
          url: '/register/region',
          data: 
          {
              country: $("#address\\.country_del").val()
          },

          type: "POST",
      }).done(function (data){});
    });
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/region")
public List<RegionData> getRegion(@RequestParam(value = "country") final String country)
{
    final String isocode = country;
    final List<RegionData> regions = i18NFacade.getRegionsForCountryIso(isocode);
    return regions;
}
```

My request and response as seen on browser:
[image]

I think the problem is with the content type of response ?!

Comment: looks you are missing the context root  in url

Comment: its `method:"post"` not `type:"post"`

Comment: @NullPointerException: Which UR? Can you please elaborate more ? Thanks.

Comment: your url should be url:'/contextroot/register/region'

Comment: @NullPointerException: Actually the URL is correct. I am able to hit my POST method in Controller.  Its just that the response is failing.

Comment: if you can hit the controller then how come you get 404? if that is the case then your controller or filter should have rule to respond back with 404 under certain condition

Comment: @NullPointerException: That's the problem. The controller is getting hit and returning a List but the AJAX call is still not entering the success function(). I have added my Controller code as well.

Comment: please try removing /region/ from your url or add /register to request mapping in your controller

Comment: Then It looks like the issue with view resolver because instead of returning JSON its getting resolved to jsp.

Comment: @NullPointerException : Yes. Exactly. So, should I try returning a proper JSP from the controller?

Comment: No you need to retun JSON  from this method and you need to check how code is configured to resolve the views

Comment: You can try this to see if it works on your method
`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/region" ,produces="application/json")

@ResponseBody`

Comment: So, should I stay with the original List<RegionData> or should I add more fields in @RequestMapping like produces? How exactly should I return a JSON? The current view resolver logic simply finds a JSP with the name of the String returned.

Comment: Yes the spring should automatically convert  that list into json and add @ResponseBody as well

Comment: O EM GEE.... @NullPointerException: Are you awesome or are you awesome... It works :) Thanks a ton !!! Feel free to ask for my kidney any day of the year ..... :)

Comment: I will just put this in answer so that in case someone else needs to refer and you can accept it if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is your view resolver as you can see that your response from  your controller class is resolved to jsp

> HTTP Status 404 - /mycustomproject/en/WEB-INF/views/desktop/register/region.jsp

So you need to let your method in your controller know that it needs to return a JSON

You can do that annotating the method by `@ResponseBody`

`@ResponseBody`, what it does is that it return object as the body, in the format specified in `produces="application/json"`.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/region" ,produces="application/json") 
@ResponseBody
public List<RegionData> getRegion(@RequestParam(value = "country") final String country)
  {
    final String isocode = country;
    final List<RegionData> regions = i18NFacade.getRegionsForCountryIso(isocode);
    return regions;
}
```

Comment: Now I am able to get a proper AJAX call but how do I retrieve this data and show it in my JSP? I have a dropdown that takes items="${regions}"